# CASE statement within WHERE clause in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, where-clause, case-statement

I want to write a `CASE` statement to find the data between two dates based on `@sFRomDate` empty or not. Given below query not working as per my requirement. Please help me to find a proper solution

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    tbl_emp_data 
WHERE
    CASE 
       WHEN @sFRomDate!='' 
          THEN SubmissionDate BETWEEN @sFRomDate AND DATEADD(DAY,1,@sToDate) 
       ELSE
          SubmissionDate = NULL
    END
```

Comment: What you are trying to do won't work.  How do you want to handle the case where `@sFRomDate` is empty (or `NULL`) ?

Comment: `CASE` is an **expression** in T-SQL (like `a+b`) that ultimately returns a single, atomic value. You **cannot** use it to control the flow of your code, or run snippets of code conditionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be the logic you were trying to implement.  In the event that `@sFRomDate` be `NULL` or empty *and* `SubmissionDate` also be `NULL` or empty the record will be returned.  Otherwise, the `SubmissionDate` will be checked to make sure it is within the range you defined.

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_emp_data
WHERE (COALESCE(@sFRomDate, '') = '' AND
       COALESCE(SubmissionDate, '') = '') OR
      (COALESCE(@sFRomDate, '') <> ''     AND
       COALESCE(SubmissionDate, '') <> '' AND
       SubmissionDate BETWEEN @sFRomDate AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, @sToDate))
```

Comment: No, if sFRomDate be null or empty, then I want to fetch the data where SubmissionDate is empty or Null, else I have to check between the dates

Comment: I implemented your logic verbatim as I understood it.  Really I think you have a design problem.  You should include sample input and output showing all the edge cases.

Comment: Thanks, Now I am getting the proper output

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want, I think it becomes simpler to follow the logic if you write:

```
IF @sFromDate = ''
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM tbl_emp_data where SubmissionDate=null
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM tbl_emp_data where SubmissionDate between @sFRomDate and DATEADD(DAY,1,@sToDate)
END
```

But as @Tim Biegeleisen says, be careful with nulls, not just for @sFromDate but also @sToDate